# Mysql - Specific Columns from certain days

Tags: mysql

I have a database that records the number of transactions each cashier makes per hour.

The column names:

```
NAME        00  01  02  03  04  05  06 07  08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23 DATE
```

00 would be midnight, 01 would be 1am, 18 would be 6pm and so on.

An average row would look like this:

```
    John Doe  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0 26 24 32  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  02/23/2014 
    John Doe  0  0  0  0  0  23  43  25  36  42  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  02/22/2014
```

I am trying to get different columns from different days in the same query.

For instance, let's say I want 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 from 02/22/2014 and 10, 11,12 from 2/23/2014 for John Doe. This would be the total hours transaction John Doe did all weekend.

Let's say John Doe has a row for most of the days this month. How would I get one line that showed me only the hours 05,06,07,08 and 09 from 2/22/2014 along with only the hours 10, 11, 12 from 02/23/2014 and no other dates/hours?

I tried this:

```
SELECT cashier.name AS NAME, 
(SELECT cashier.05 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-22' AND t.name = cashier.name) as '05', 
(SELECT cashier.06 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-22' AND t.name = cashier.name) as '06', 
(SELECT cashier.07 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-22' AND t.name = cashier.name) as '07',
(SELECT cashier.08 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-22' AND t.name = cashier.name) as '08',
(SELECT cashier.09 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-22' AND t.name = cashier.name) as '09', 
(SELECT cashier.10 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-23' AND t.name = cashier.name) as '10',
(SELECT cashier.11 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-23' AND t.name = cashier.name) as '11',
(SELECT cashier.12 FROM cashier AS t WHERE date = '2014-02-23'  AND t.name = cashier.name) as '12'
FROM cashier
WHERE NAME = 'John Doe'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT f.name , f.17,
(SELECT t.05 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-22') AS '05',
(SELECT t.06 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-22') AS '06',
(SELECT t.07 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-22') AS '07',
(SELECT t.08 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-22') AS '08',
(SELECT t.09 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-22') AS '09',
(SELECT t.10 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-23') AS '10',
(SELECT t.11 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-23') AS '11',
(SELECT t.12 FROM cashier AS t WHERE f.name = t.name AND t.date = '2014-02-23') AS '12'
FROM cashier AS f
WHERE date = '2014-02-22' 
AND f.18 > 0");
```